# When i upload multiple images to my database using codeigniter the file url is wrong but image is inserting in folder and database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i know it might be wrong to ask but when i am inserting multiple image using ajax and inserting it to the database files are getting inserted but the url is wrong let me show you

""http://localhost/P_Display/uploads/bike-926023_192048.jpg""

this is the url that i got from the console the file is saving but it might be because of the for loop that i am using to upload multiple files

let me show you the controller code

```
public function post_data_multimage()
{
$data = array();
  $data['title'] = 'Multiple file upload';
  if($this->input->post())
  {
    // retrieve the number of images uploaded;
   $number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['multimage']['tmp_name']);
    $files = $_FILES['multimage'];
    $errors = array();

for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++)
    {
      if($_FILES['multimage']['error'][$i] != 0) $errors[$i][] = 'Couldnt upload file '.$_FILES['multimage']['name'][$i];
    }
     if(sizeof($errors)==0)
    {
      // now, taking into account that there can be more than one file, for each file we will have to do the upload
      // we first load the upload library
      $this->load->library('upload');
      // next we pass the upload path for the images
      $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . './uploads/';
      // also, we make sure we allow only certain type of images
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
       for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
        $_FILES['multimage']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['multimage']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['multimage']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['multimage']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['multimage']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
        //now we initialize the upload library
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

         $image= $_FILES['multimage']['name'];

        $post = $this->input->post();

          unset($post['submit']);

        $this->load->model('Pmodel');
       $multi_data= $this->Pmodel->post_data_multimage($post,$image);


        // we retrieve the number of files that were uploaded
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('multimage'))
        {
           $data['uploads'][$i] = $this->upload->data();
          $upload_data=$data['uploads'][$i];
          $image_path= base_url("uploads/".$upload_data['raw_name'].$upload_data['file_ext']);
         echo json_encode($image_path);
        }
        else
        {
          $data['upload_errors'][$i] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
      }
    }
       else
    {
      print_r($errors);
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
  }
  else
  {
   echo "string";
  }
}
```

how can i remove those slashes from my url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this might work all we need is to add a html element to the controller that will echo the image from the controller and we don't need to pass the value to the view thus ending the conflict of wrong url

here is my code

```
$data = array();
  $data['title'] = 'Multiple file upload';
  if($this->input->post())
  {
    // retrieve the number of images uploaded;
   $number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['multimage']['tmp_name']);
    $files = $_FILES['multimage'];
    $errors = array();

for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++)
    {
      if($_FILES['multimage']['error'][$i] != 0) $errors[$i][] = 'Couldnt upload file '.$_FILES['multimage']['name'][$i];
    }
     if(sizeof($errors)==0)
    {
      // now, taking into account that there can be more than one file, for each file we will have to do the upload
      // we first load the upload library
      $this->load->library('upload');
      // next we pass the upload path for the images
      $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . './uploads/';
      // also, we make sure we allow only certain type of images
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
       for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
        $_FILES['multimage']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['multimage']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['multimage']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['multimage']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['multimage']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
        //now we initialize the upload library
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

         $image= $_FILES['multimage']['name'];

        $post = $this->input->post();

          unset($post['submit']);

        $this->load->model('Pmodel');
       $multi_data= $this->Pmodel->post_data_multimage($post,$image);


        // we retrieve the number of files that were uploaded
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('multimage'))
        {
           $data['uploads'][$i] = $this->upload->data();
          $upload_data=$data['uploads'][$i];

           $user_image = array( 'src' => base_url("uploads/" .$image),
                                                            'width' => '100px',
                                                            'height'=> '100px',
                                                            );
        echo  "<a href='#'>" . img($user_image)."</a>";

        }
        else
        {
          $data['upload_errors'][$i] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
      }
    }
       else
    {
      print_r($errors);
    }

  }
  else
  {
   echo "string";
  }
}
```

see i just echo the image with its path thus removing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

save the address same

`'Assets/image_upload/'.$image= $_FILES['multimage']['name']`

to field image table of database if exist.

When you show it.

`echo(base_url($item->image))//image field showed in database.`

Comment: This is my solution.

Comment: your solution is correct but i dont need to add address to my database i just want to display my image and that can happen without image path insertion.

Comment: You can save base_url('Assets/image_upload/'). $image= $_FILES['multimage']['name'] into database field.